# Too many connections in an email system in a2 hosting

Tags: laravel-5

In my Laravel web application, when I send a message to all registered users, an exception occurs saying there are too many connections.

Some posts say I should change `grep smtp_accept_max` in the service configuration.

Where can I find that configuration in a2 hosting cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on A2 too. It's not possible to change this setting through cPanel. But you can create you own php.ini [as explained here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/custom-php.ini-files).

There are couple of things to consider. A2 is [not a fan of bulk email sending](http://%20https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/does-a2-hosting-support/do-you-support-sending-bulk-mail) from their servers, as [explained in their TOS](https://www.a2hosting.com/about/policies/acceptable-use-policy#1.-Accepted-Uses). I had a warning once and was suspended.

(*The mail service of your Lite Web Hosting - Singapore account with username xxxxxxxx on sgss2.a2hosting.com has been suspended. The suspension is due to large volumes of email sent from the account.*)

In time, as your website grows, you will have to rely on 3th party services, as the very affordable [Amazon SES functionality](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com). Personally I use SES in combination with the (since 5.7) [Laravel Email Verification method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification). SES is not a fan of bouncing emails. Above a certain percentage they could suspend that service to you.

If the volume is reasonable, you could for now either loop the emails one by one in a PHP loop or [create a queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues).

It looks like changing the value of `smpt_acceps_max` could [simply ignore higher volumes](https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=14318).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned a lot and I can try much more possibilities from your comments.